# How to remove annotations added as MKAnnotationView objects

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am new to using MapKit framework.

I am adding an image to MKAnnotationView object at specific lat-long pair on map, say at (latA, longA).

For the next iteration, i need to remove the annotation added and add new annotation at different lat-long pair, say at (latB, longB).

Let me know of any help.

Thanks
@dity@

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Remove the annotation
[self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];

Step2: Change/Recreate the annotation, and add it back
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation]